# Differentiatiable functions question

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Suppose that $f:(0,∞)↦(0,∞)$ is any differentiable function with the property that $f(\frac{1}{x})=f(x)$ for all $x\in (0,∞)$. Show that $f'(1)=0$

Honestly don't even know where to begin with this question, can anyone give me some hints please?

Answer (score 0):

Let us note $g : x \to f(1/x)$. By hypothesis $g=f$ hence $g'(1) =f'(1)$.

On the other hand, applying chain rule, we get $$g'(x) = -\frac{f'(1/x)}{x^2},$$ hence $g'(1) = -f'(1)$.